# How to replace current page in Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this flow:

Contacts page -> navController.push(NewContact) -> navController.push(ContactCreated)

How do I make that on the ContactCreated page the "Back" button return user to root "Contacts" page instead of the NewContact page? So I would like to replace a page in the navigation stack.

I'm using Ionic 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as shown below. Here is the [**doc**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Navbar/#backButtonClick).

```
import { Navbar } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-page',
  template: `
    <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
           Your Page
        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
    ...
    </ion-content>
   `
})
export class YourPage {
  @ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;
  constructor(private navController: NavController){}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e:UIEvent)=>{
      this.navController.setRoot('Contacts');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `popToRoot()` [function](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#popToRoot) instead of `pop()`.

```
this.navCtrl.popToRoot ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `pop` immediately followed by `push` with disabled animation:

```
this.navCtrl.pop({animate: false});
this.navCtrl.push(ContactCreated, null, {animate: false});
```

Comment: nice solution but it will pass for the background page, calling ionViewWillEnter etc.. that in some case is a problem

Answer (score 1):

This way you add the page on top of the stack, and next remove the actual from the second position, without invoking any other page enter events:

```
self.navCtrl.push(NextPage, nextParams).then(()=>{
    let index = self.viewCtrl.index;
    self.navCtrl.remove(index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the last page in the navigation stack, you can do it like this:

```
navController.pop()
    .then(() => navController.push(ContactCreated))
    .catch(() => navController.push(ContactCreated));
```